# Is there an online alternative to iGoogle

Tags: rss, igoogle, rss-reader

iGoogle [will be retired](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2664197) on November 1, 2013. It is possible to [export its settings](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=107519&topic=1678516&ctx=topic) in an XML form.

Is there an online alternative that can import iGoogle's settings and save the need to migrate many feeds one by one?

[my.yahoo.com](http://my.yahoo.com), for example, is online but does it have an import / export option?

**EDIT (I):**
[Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5923751/two-excellent-customizable-start-pages-worth-trying-now-that-igoogles-going-away?utm_campaign=socialflow_lifehacker_facebook&utm_source=lifehacker_facebook&utm_medium=socialflow) now also addresses the issue and suggests [NetVibes](http://www.netvibes.com) or [Protopage](http://protopage.com/).

**EDIT (II):**

- So far, [Netvibes](http://www.netvibes.com) seems to allow the smoothest transition from iGoogle, allowing for a multi-tab and multi-column view as well as easy import (see their [FAQ](http://faq.netvibes.com/how_to_switch_from_my_old_service_to_netvibes))
- Feedly resmbles mostly Google reader (does not seem to support multiple columns) and has limited import options
- protopage: supports importing from an opml file of feeds but they then need to be added one by one to the page

Comment: I coded a minimalistic ad free version of google (only rss widgets): http://www.fyrup.com It has google suggestions and an easy to use interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are few you can explore:

- [Netvibes](http://www.netvibes.com/)
- [Ustart](http://www.ustart.org/)
- [ProtoPage](http://protopage.com/)
- [Feedly](http://feedly.com/)
- [MyFav](http://myfav.es/)
- [Aboogy](http://www.aboogy.com/)
- [Iguzu](http://iguzu.com/)

Comment: See also @TimMaschine [answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/28651/6497) for [how to export iGoogle Feeds to OPML format](http://googlesystem.blogspot.co.il/2008/07/export-igoogle-feeds-to-opml.html)

Answer (score 4):

I'm trying out [Netvibes](http://www.netvibes.com) and that actually seems quite nice, very similar to iGoogle in a lot of ways and potentially more powerful - already got it set up to check my emails accounts etc.

Not sure it is able to migrate feeds though, although I might not have come across that option yet - at the moment i'm just manually bringing across each of my RSS feeds.

Answer (score 4):

**If you just want the links:**

[Export iGoogle Feeds](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/07/export-igoogle-feeds-to-opml.html)

Follow the steps to export convert to OPML and then load into Google Reader

Other options:

Maybe put [this on a free google app engine](http://code.google.com/p/gloudy/)

Comment: Although Google reader is discontinued, an OPML file is very helpful for migrating all the feeds to the new site.

Answer (score 1):

[Alternatives to iGoogle](http://google-sucks.org/directory/index.php?c=21) shows [NetVibes](http://www.netvibes.com/en) and [PageFlakes](http://www.pageflakes.com/) as alternatives.

This [Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5923751/two-excellent-customizable-start-pages-worth-trying-now-that-igoogles-going-away) compares [NetVibes](http://www.netvibes.com/en) and [Protopage](http://protopage.com/).

This [discussion](http://www.readreactreview.com/2012/07/05/seeking-an-alternative-to-igoogle-any-ideas/) also mentions Yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

Take this as a blessing in disguise. It’s time to upgrade from the dashboard widget life of the 2005 start pages into a better designed experience.

Before it shuts down, please give [Skim.Me](http://skim.me) a try. I'm a founder. We make your daily online routine more productive and have been working on this for the past year.

Your routine sources (not just news and social media) are automatically setup, personalized and managed for you. Browse content from your sources in timed batches throughout the day and see how much you've accomplished, never how many unread you have. All the content is viewed in our app instead of linking you outside to new tabs. Releasing summer 2012!

Answer (score 0):

New one just came out called [igHome](http://www.ighome.com/). According to [PCWorld](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2010900/ighome-gives-displaced-igoogle-users-a-familiar-home.html) it "works just like iGoogle".

> Maybe now there is: igHome is a personalized home page that bears more than a passing resemblance to early-day iGoogle.
>
> In other words, it's a home page you can customize with a variety of feeds and gadgets, arranging them all to your liking. You might have a news window here, a weather update there, a clock, a blog feed, and so on.
>
> Developer Mike Sutton says his goal was "to create a site that looked and worked like iGoogle as much as possible to make the transition easy for users."

Comment: I could not find an import option

Comment: I've not used it. I was just passing the information along.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried MyYahoo and its ok, but it was time to move on. So I reviewed netvibes and it looks like way too much for me! I tried protopage’s demo and it seems promising. Then I got this invitation to try homepagey. It’s very new but looked pretty good. I am currently using it and I most likely will keep it. Not  Igoogle by any means, but very nice. If any one is interested here is there website [Homepagey](http://homepagey.com). I don’t know what’s up with the invitation thing, but if you contact them in time you will get one?

Comment: Is there an import function as the original poster requested?

Comment: Perhaps you can add some styling to your answer? You mention many products. Styling will make them more visible. See the [faq] to know more.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to iGoogle for RSS gadgets, I suggest this simple webapp: http://rssdashboard.appspot.com/

Comment: Will this allow importing of iGoogle settings and feeds?

Comment: Yes you can import your iGoogle settings. Note that, once imported, you can re-export your settings and thus use this webapp to convert your iGoogle settings into OPML.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [Den](http://den.io). It doesn't import iGoogle XML, but it does import/export OPML. If you have a Google Reader subscriptions XML file that would work. I haven't had much luck with [converting iGoogle XML to OPML](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/07/export-igoogle-feeds-to-opml.html), but it's still worth a shot.

Full disclosure: I built it.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I am using [startific.com](http://startific.com/) . Much more powerful than iGoogle, it's more than just an alternative/replacement.

Comment: How do you import iGoogle settings into this?

Comment: Already mentioned in an earlier reply

Comment: Also a spammer on Super User.

Answer (score -3):

Add another to the list, ighome.com.  It looks and feels a lot more like igoogle than any of the previously listed alternatives.  I haven't quite figured out how they make money (this might be another protopage disaster).

Comment: Already mention in [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/33364/354).